# Msdeploy 401 while trying to sync directories

Tags: msdeploy, http-status-code-401

I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.tech-fellow.net/2012/12/deploy-windows-service-on-remote-machine-with-msdeploy/) about using msdeploy to deploy a windows service.

I have this command running locally against my iis server and against a remote server and get the same error with both.

```
-verb:sync
-preSync:runCommand='C:/deploy/presync.cmd',waitInterval=30000
-source:dirPath='C:/deploy/service'
-dest:
  dirPath='C:/Websites/service',
  computerName=localhost,
  userName='username',password='password',
  authtype='basic'
-allowUntrusted
-postSync:runCommand='C:/deploy/postsync.cmd',waitInterval=30000"
```

This is the error that I get

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
More Information: Connected to 'localhost' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'localhost'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/f
wlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Error count: 1.
```

However I can get this command to work ok without errors to run a bunch of commands through the manifest and create the website.

```
-verb:sync,
-source:manifest=C:\deploy\manifest.xml",
-dest:auto,
      computerName='localhost',
      userName='username',
      password='password',
      authtype='basic'
```

Any ideas why the the directory copy throws and authorisation error?

The user is definitely an admin as i've created a new user and added them to administrators group.  What's confusing me is that the manifest works but the directory copy doesn't.  I'm clearly doing something wrong with the settings here.

Comment: FYI, you should probably stick to using backslashes (`\`) in your paths, rather than forward slashes (`/`).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything specific, but I'd recommend you open up Event Viewer (`eventvwr`) and take a look at the Web Deploy application event log and the Security event log (for failed logins).